# Accessing self.view from a static library

Tags: iphone, uiview, static-libraries, subview

So I'm making a static library for iOS. Basically I want people to be able to call something like this:

```
[MyStaticLibrary showview]
```

And my static library to add a subview to their current view. Normally I might do something like this:

```
CGRect mainframe = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UIView *mView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:mainframe];
//Add some stuff to the view
[self.view addSubview:mView];
```

But xcode is complaining, and rightfully so, that I can't access self.view from the static library since I'm currently using an NSObject in my static library. Is there anyway for me to access the "self.view" from my static library so I can add a view to the application screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You could adapt your `showview` method to be `showViewInParentView:` and allow the caller to give you the view you need.

2) You could use `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:mView]` to add the library's view directly to the window, ensuring that it is on top.

I recommend #1 over #2.

Comment: I tested the second way... but when I call [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] from my stati library the window il nil.. why??